# How to Touch Three Buttons for One Touch Android

Tags: android, android-layout, button, imagebutton

I am new in the Android. I can not touch the three buttons at one time This code I can click on the three buttons but not the One Touch. I have researched a lot but I did not find the solution I tried to use `OnCilckListener()`  but `OnTouchListener()` could not find a way
I want to give me an example or a tip. And you can see in the picture. Please help me, thank you

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity{
    Button a,b,c;
    int a1 = 0;

     @Override
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
          super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
          setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //a = (Button)findView...;
    //b = ....;
    //c = ....;

a.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

    a1 = 1; 
    b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

        if(a1 == 1){
           a1 = 2;  
    c.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

        if(a1 == 2){

        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Toast", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();   
        a1 = 0;
        }}});       
       }

    }});
  }

     }); 


    }
```

[image]

Comment: From your example usage, this does not look to be provide a good user experience. Swiping over three buttons does not seem to be a natural use case. Have you thought of a using a different input method to provide the same end result for the user?

Comment: Your words are true This is just an example to understand how this is done Give me an example in another way if you want to thank you

Comment: this looks like a bad idea in general, but anyway, the view that handles the touch down event is also the one that will receive the touch up, you might want to handle this situation in a container view

Answer (score 1):

Put the 3 buttons in a single parent view.  Have the parent view implement the swiping behavior.  Then have the parent view override `onInterceptTouchEvent` to return true for all touches.  That way the parent view will handle all touches for all of its children, and you just have a basic swipe detector.

Comment: I am new I am new in the Android Give me an example or more explanation about using view implement the swiping behavior  I can not perform the main display to perform the beating behavior I'm confused when I read it is executed by ViewGroup Give me an example code please help me thank you

Answer (score 0):

Attach an `onTouchListener` to the layout containing the three buttons. Check each touch for an ACTION_DOWN (putting the finger down) that is inside the bounds of the first view. Then look for the next ACTION_UP (releasing the initial touch) to be inside the bounds of the third view. You can check whether a touch event is in the bounds of a view with the following code:

```
public static boolean hitTest(View v, int x, int y) {
final int tx = (int) (ViewCompat.getTranslationX(v) + 0.5f);
final int ty = (int) (ViewCompat.getTranslationY(v) + 0.5f);
final int left = v.getLeft() + tx;
final int right = v.getRight() + tx;
final int top = v.getTop() + ty;
final int bottom = v.getBottom() + ty;

return (x >= left) && (x <= right) && (y >= top) && (y <= bottom);
```

}

Comment: How it is done releasing the initial touchcase. MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:

Comment: When the user touches the screen a `MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN` is fired. When they move their finger, one or more `MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE` are fired. And when they finally release/raise their finger, a `MotionEvent.ACTION_UP` is fired. These are the types of events that will be given to your `onTouchListener`
Perhaps it's better for you to read a tutorial like : http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidTouch/article.html#android-touch-basics

Comment: Thank you for this useful lesson . I knew how to do a multi touch with two fingers at the same time And the use of (x) and (y) . But so far I could not touch the three buttons with one finger as in the question I tried to execute your instructions but could not find the solution. You can give me a complete and simplified example  It helps me a lot to understand how this is done .
I thank you very much

Comment: If you know how to do a multi touch, you should be able to figure this out. And if you can't look for an online tutorial blog/video. This is very basic and there are many resources on it. I've already given you the rather complex logic, i'm opting out of teaching you how to set an `OnTouchListener`. Go to the Android Documentation and read about `OnTouchListeners` and what the callback means.

Comment: Multi touch does not give me the desired result I do not need to use two fingers. I read but could not reach a solution.  If I could reach a solution I did not ask this question. It was possible to write a simple example that contains two or three buttons but  I think you did not understand the question in general Thank you for giving me some of your time

Comment: lol I understand your question, i've never even mentioned multi touch as a possible solution because it is not.